# Reminders to mark an answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request, accepted-answer

It annoys me somewhat when someone asks a question and you see people give fantastic, well researched, answers, but still they don't mark the question as answered.

Is there any mechanism that reminds people to look and see if an answer answers their question?  Something simple like a notification like the one that we get for new badges would be great after say 2 weeks.

I think the majority of the time people just forget to do it, so any sort of simple reminder would be great.

Comment: There is a reminder on the user page above each of the answered questions that says "Have you considered accepting an answer for this question" or similar, it shows after a week or so. Are you suggesting a notification that pops up during more normal use of the site? I don't know how often people check the answers part of the profile honestly.

Comment: I'm suggesting a flash that shows in the same way that we are notified of badges at the top of the screen in every page.

Comment: I noticed we have a similar system in place to encourage voting on questions; if you vote on a bunch of answers it gives you a pop up reminding you to vote on answers too. I don't know when this one should be shown to the user though aide from just a flash message after X period of time.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered the possibility that while the answer may seem fantastic to you, the OP might not find it as valuable and is therefore not marking it as accepted in hopes that someone may answer it in a way more to their liking?

Comment: Yes, I have.  And just like the notifications that we get at present for badges, you can simply click to make it go away.  Nobody said anything about forcing someone to choose an answer.

Comment: Unfortunately on UX it seems more people think "These are all great answers...I'll just not mark _any_ of them correct..."

Comment: It would be really handy if the OP would comment on (at least the highly-rated) answers he or she has already received detailing the points they feel aren't answered adequately by the answerer. Otherwise how does an answerer know to revise their answer?

Answer (score 0):

I have a low accept rate because sometimes there is no clear consensus on the answer and it would be unfair and subjective to mark one as more right than another. Where there is clear consensus I will mark accordingly. See this as crowd sourced acceptance.

Come to think of it, I think the answer accepting feature is redundant.

Comment: As far as I understand it, accepting answers is built for a situation where there can be a definitively correct answer that works for the person asking the question. This may or may not be more prevalent or applicable on other stackexchange sites, I guess.

Answer (score -1):

First, let me say I heartily endorse this proposal, although I'm not sure I agree on its implementation. I think an inbox message that tells you to consider accepting an answer (especially if you have a +10/"nice" answer on the question). That glowing red indicator gets much more attention from me than the giant flash messages.

While I haven't asked any questions at all (preferring to answer them instead), my instinct tells me that there's a rep disincentive to marking an answer as "accepted".

Once a question has been accepted as answered it is no longer shown in some question filters. It also inhibits someone who may otherwise be willing to do extensive research into your question from answering at all (since they cannot receive the tick). I believe the question is therefore less likely to be visited, and also less likely to be upvoted itself (both being factors in badges or rep).

Cynically, I'm surprised people accept any answers at all!